# Asking about a visual tool in SO

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've imagined a tool where you can write your name and see all the people affected by your posts in a nice graphical view.

Your account can be a node in the middle surrounded with the profiles (other nodes) that were "affected" by you. The nodes can be connected to each other.

You can select the level of people affected (the people affected by me or the people affected by me and the people affected by them and so on)

---

[image: The illustration]

Comment: You have a question? Is this related to Stack Exchange or something else?

Comment: If this is just about Stack Overflow, then it should go on their [meta](https://www,meta.stackoverflow.com). Questions about the whole of Stack Exchange go here. See [What's Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for more information

Comment: Is this about the "people reached" on our profile pages? You want a graphical tool? A graph that shows _who_ you affected?

Comment: @JakeSymons my proposition does work for all stackexchange sites

Comment: @S.L.Barth I want a graphical tool on the SO website that shows the people that are affected by your posts/edits/comments/.. in a the way I described

Comment: @ziMtyth Well, as you see the way you described is found quite unclear. Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman as they say one image = 1000 words, I will add an image to illustrate my idea

Comment: How do you define the "affected" relation? Some function of votes? Some function of  favorited questions? Some function of comments? Some function of edits? Some function of profile views?

Comment: That tool exists. Mods use it when investigating vote rings :)

Comment: @PeterMortensen these question can be answerd by all of us, it's a decision that can  be made by all of us  =)

Comment: @Won't can you orivide a link please

Comment: No, I can't provide a link. You can run for mod next election and they'll let you see it, if you win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fun idea.

I don't think Stack Exchange will build this, because it doesn't seem to add much value. It doesn't help users with their day-to-day use of the site.

But... you can build it yourself! You could even release it as a [Stack App](https://stackapps.com) so others can use it too.

I've looked on Stack Apps if there was something similar, and haven't found it.

So, if you feel like making this yourself... check out the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), and enjoy the coding!

Comment: Thank you for the encouragement =), I agree with you in this part: "It doesn't help users with their day-to-day use of the site", but I believe that people are very interested on there reputation, badges and the help they provide to people, so my idea can help in PRESENTING the help provided by a person in better way then "people reached"

Comment: Unless (some function of) voting needs to be included in the "affected" relation.

Comment: @PeterMortensen it needs to be decided